# Which disk to choose when doing a clean install of MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina

Right now I am doing a clean install of Catalina. I have erased the Macintosh HD and the Macintosh HD -Data. When I tried to install the OS it gave me these two choices again. I couldn’t find anything on apple’s website on this choice of drives. I chose now the Macintosh HD because it is defined as the system drive but I am not sure. I would be happy if you provide some information or a reference about this.

Comment: Did you see the Apple doc [How to erase a disk for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496)?  Before re-installing you first need to, from recovery, **delete**  the volume *"Macintosh HD - Data"*  and then **erase** *"Macintosh HD"*.

Comment: Yeah I was erasing the "Macintosh HD - Data" not deleting it. That solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was erasing the parent volume of these partitions as "Macintosh HD", leaving one partition.

Another option, as per lx08's comment, is to delete "Macintosh HD - Data" and erase "Macintosh HD".